# Button inside a table does not work clicking at all

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that when clicked changes its status within a table, when I load the page and click on any one, it only activates the first one from above and the others do not, and also it does not return to the previous status, I would like to know the that I'm doing wrong.

[image]

In the image above, when I click on any one, it activates only the first one and does not deactivate it back,

And the 3rd has already been activated and I can't move it, I think there's something wrong with the map or something...

```js
{
    this.state.dataSource.map((data) => {
        function ChangeIcon(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (data.statusPedido === "Em aberto") {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn-times");
                btn.style.display = "none";

                var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn-check");
                btn2.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{data.nrPedido}</td>
                <td>{data.dataPedido}</td>
                <td>{data.dtEntrega}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDoses}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDosesConvencionais}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDosesCervicais}</td>
                <td>{data.rota}</td>
                <td>{data.periodoLactacao}</td>
                <td>{data.plantelMatrizes}</td>
                <td>{data.porcentagemReposicaoLeitoas}</td>

                <td>
                    {data.statusPedido === "Em aberto" ? (
                        <div>
                            <button
                                className="btn"
                                onClick={ChangeIcon}
                                style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                                id="btn-times"
                            >
                                <FontAwesome name="times" />
                            </button>
                            <button
                                className="btn"
                                id="btn-check"
                                style={{ display: "none", backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                            >
                                <FontAwesome name="check" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <button
                            className="btn"
                            style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                            id="btn-check"
                        >
                            <FontAwesome name="check" />{" "}
                        </button>
                    )}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: You had a missing closing </tr> tag, I fixed it in the format edit.

Comment: I didn't copy the tag in the example, but it is closed hehe

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you render a list of elements produced by a map function, but you forgot to assign keys to the elements (tr's in your case). Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Without keys, you can get a lot of hard to catch bugs because React does not understand which row to update. The best choice for a key would be an ID or other unique string to identify each row in this table.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, but I'm not getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right! The problem is with the map method. The reason is that you're not providing a unique key property for each returned element.
You can fix it this way:

```html
{
    // Add an index argument
    this.state.dataSource.map((data, index) => {
        function ChangeIcon(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (data.statusPedido === "Em aberto") {
                var btn = document.getElementById("btn-times");
                btn.style.display = "none";

                var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn-check");
                btn2.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
        return (
        // Use that index here as key property
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{data.nrPedido}</td>
                <td>{data.dataPedido}</td>
                <td>{data.dtEntrega}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDoses}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDosesConvencionais}</td>
                <td>{data.totalDosesCervicais}</td>
                <td>{data.rota}</td>
                <td>{data.periodoLactacao}</td>
                <td>{data.plantelMatrizes}</td>
                <td>{data.porcentagemReposicaoLeitoas}</td>

                <td>
                    {data.statusPedido === "Em aberto" ? (
                        <div>
                            <button
                                className="btn"
                                onClick={ChangeIcon}
                                style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                                id="btn-times"
                            >
                                <FontAwesome name="times" />
                            </button>
                            <button
                                className="btn"
                                id="btn-check"
                                style={{ display: "none", backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                            >
                                <FontAwesome name="check" />
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <button
                            className="btn"
                            style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                            id="btn-check"
                        >
                            <FontAwesome name="check" />{" "}
                        </button>
                    )}
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
}
```

To know more about Lists and Keys in React, you can check the [The official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: I added this same code and it didn't work, it was the same format

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with the conditional rendering you are doing. In that case, try this:

```
{data.statusPedido === "Em aberto" ? (
                        <button
                            className="btn"
                            onClick={ChangeIcon}
                            style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                            id="btn-times"
                        >
                            <FontAwesome name="times" />
                        </button>
                ) : (
                   <button
                            className="btn"
                            id="btn-check"
                            style={{ display: "none", backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
                        >
                            <FontAwesome name="check" />
                        </button>
                )}
```

Now, it will return either a "check" button or an "X" button. Also:

- Avoid to name functions with capital cases, that's reserved for classes. Your code will still work, but it's not respecting the standard.
- You don't even need to call event.preventDefault() since a button doesn't have a default behaviour like a "submit' or "clear" input.